# JQuery onClick activating every element on page with class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got an element on my HTML page:

```
<div class="edit-post">
    <input type="image" src="static/media/icons/expand_plus.png" class="expand-post-menu"/>
    <div class="edit-tools">
        <a class="edit-tool-btn" href="/edit/{{ post.post_id }}">Edit</a>
        <a class="edit-tool-btn" href="/delete/{{ post.post_id }}">Delete</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

which will be repeated many times on the page.

My JQuery onClick function:

```
$(".expand-post-menu").click(function() {
  $(".edit-tools").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

Now my problem is that everytime I activate any of the .expand-post-menu buttons, the slideToggle function is called on every element with the .edit-tools class. How can I make it so that only the elements of the clicked button are activated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `this` context to tell which expand element was clicked
2. Use `.next()` to get the correct edit div

```js
$(".expand-post-menu").click(function() {
  $(this).next(".edit-tools").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="edit-post">
  <input type="image" src="static/media/icons/expand_plus.png" class="expand-post-menu" />
  <div class="edit-tools">
    <a class="edit-tool-btn" href="/edit/{{ post.post_id }}">Edit</a>
    <a class="edit-tool-btn" href="/delete/{{ post.post_id }}">Delete</a>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="edit-post">
  <input type="image" src="static/media/icons/expand_plus.png" class="expand-post-menu" />
  <div class="edit-tools">
    <a class="edit-tool-btn" href="/edit/{{ post.post_id }}">Edit</a>
    <a class="edit-tool-btn" href="/delete/{{ post.post_id }}">Delete</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `this` to reference the clicked element, and from it, navigate to the `.edit-tools`:

```js
$(".expand-post-menu").click(function() {
  $(this).next().slideToggle("slow");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="edit-post">
  <input type="image" src="static/media/icons/expand_plus.png" class="expand-post-menu" />
  <div class="edit-tools">
    <a class="edit-tool-btn" href="/edit/{{ post.post_id }}">Edit</a>
    <a class="edit-tool-btn" href="/delete/{{ post.post_id }}">Delete</a>
  </div>
</div>
```